# Nested For Loops, Unable to store Iterations without Catch 22

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

In the beginning I have a master list I intend to put everything in:

```
master_list = []
```

I have data stored in nested lists like this:

```
multi_list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
```

The end result needs to have this data converted to a list of dicts like this:

```
master_list
>> [{'x1':1,'x2':2,'y1':3,'y2':4,'id':5},{'x1':6,'x2':7,'y1':8,'y2':9,'id':10}]
```

So that's my end goal. My approach to reach this goal was as follows:

```
multi_list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
master_list = []
iterating_dict = {}
for n in multi_list:
    for idx,i in enumerate(['x1','x2','y1','y2','id']):
        iterating_dict[i] = n[idx]
    master_list.append(iterating_dict)

master_list
>>[{'x1':6,'x2':7,'y1':8,'y2':9,'id':10},{'x1':6,'x2':7,'y1':8,'y2':9,'id':10}]
```

What ends up happening is the second item in `multi_list` is stored twice. I want it to store converted dicts for all items in `multi_list`. What I believe this means is the `append` is not in the right place of the loop. However, when I put it further inside the loop, it appends nothing to `master_list`. I can't put `append` further outside without it going out of scope.

What are some conventional approaches to this kind of difficulty in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reset iterating dict on each iteration of the external for loop. Otherwise it will keep accumulating values.

Something like this should work:

```
for n in multi_list:
    iterating_dict = {}
    for idx,i in enumerate(['x1','x2','y1','y2','id']):
        iterating_dict[i] = n[idx]
    master_list.append(iterating_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
master_list = [{key: l[i] for i, key in enumerate(['x1','x2','y1','y2','id'])} for l in multi_list]
```

try above code snippet, hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Concise way to do this in python is to use `zip` and list comprehension.

```
multi_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
dict_keys = ['x1','x2','y1','y2','id']    
master_list = [dict(zip(dict_keys, sublist)) for sublist in multi_list]
```

`zip()` combines two sequences together and `dict()` converts it into a key-value pair. That's what you're doing with each sublist in your `multi_list` and `['x1','x2','y1','y2','id']`.

So here we're making a dictionary out of a combined sequence of `['x1','x2','y1','y2','id']` and sublist for every sublist in the `multi_list`.

Comment: I think I will consider this approach next time I work with these kind of data structures. For now I have to work in this for loop environment, but thank you all the same, this is truly concise!